# Multipart upload in the cloud runs into timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, forms, spring-webflux, multipartform-data

EDIT: Solved myself. Loadbalancer problem.

I am implementing an image upload for the first time using Spring Boot with Webflux.
My application is deployed to Google Cloud Platform and is sitting behind Cloudflare. I doubt that CF is a problem in general, as all other kind of HTTP requests work fine.
I am wondering if multipart/form-data is the right approach then in first place. Because Postman gives me such a `curl` request:

```
curl --location 'protocol://some-location/properties/967275918/images' \
--form 'image=@"C:/Users/MyUser/Pictures/testimage.jpg"'
```

On my local machine it works fine with this code in the Controller, however when deployed into GCP I run into timeout.

Is POSTing a form the right approach or is my assumption correct, that I need to pass `ByteArray` from Client to Server in first place?

To not have confusing code: This Spring Boot application is a backend orchestration service. It should receive the Image and forward it to a "real" backend.

```
@RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        value = "/properties/{property-id}/images",
        consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }
)
fun uploadPropertyImage(propertyId: String, image: Flux<Part>, exchange: ServerWebExchange) : Mono<ResponseEntity<Void>> {
    return image.next()
            .map { it.headers().contentType!! }
            .flatMap { mediaType ->
                val imagePartContents = image.flatMap(Part::content)

                DataBufferUtils
                    .join(imagePartContents)
                    .flatMap { dataBuffer ->
                        val imageAsByteArray = dataBuffer.imageAsByteArray()

                        propertyApiAdapter.uploadImage(propertyId, imageAsByteArray, mediaType)
                            .map { ResponseEntity.ok().build() }
                    }
            }
    }
```

Note: Its also my first time I code Spring Webflux. Could be that my code doesn't make sense in the Cloud, however it works just fine on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out its not a coding problem, but a loadbalancer config problem. I forgot to add the new route to the reverse proxy. GCP Loadbalancer just times out when it cannot find a backend for a route.